# Django query works from the shell, but not the dev server? Raises FieldError in dev server

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been having a wtf moment with Django's ORM (django 1.3). In the development server:

```
# in x.modules.training.models
class Training(x.models.Base):
    trainers = models.ManyToManyField(staff_models.Staff, related_name='trainings_taught')
    people = models.ManyToManyField(x.models.Person, related_name='trainings_attended')

# in any view
from x.modules.staff.models import Staff
from x.models import Person

Staff.objects.filter(trainings_taught=12)
# [<Staff: Staff object>]

Person.objects.filter(trainings_attended=12)
# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'trainings_attended' into field. Choices are: address, comment, contact_for_farmers, email, farmer, first_name, id, last_name, mobile_number, modified_by, modified_timestamp, national_id, passport_number, region, version

# Why would it work for one ManyToMany and not the other?
```

Whereas in the generic python shell, (note x is on the python path) no matter what the order of the two import lines, both queries run just fine.

```
>>> from x.models import *
>>> from x import modules
>>> Person.objects.filter(trainings_attended=12)
>>> modules.staff.models.Staff.objects.filter(trainings_taught=12)
```

How can this be?

Comment: Do you have any classes inheriting from Training?

Comment: Staff does inherit from Person (OneToOne inheritence) but the fact that it works from the shell seems to preclude model validation issues (and the models do pass validation).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any class inheriting from Training Class, you must guarantee all related_name's are different. So you should declare it as:

```
people = models.ManyToManyField(x.models.Person, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_trainings_attended')
```

Comment: I have classes that inherit from Person, but not from Training.

Comment: The problem is the Staff class contains the related_name "trainings_taught" while Training also contains that. Django doesn't allow the duplicated related_name through model classes. Try my solution first.

Comment: Staff does contain trainings_taught, that works, but Training does not, Training is where the ManyToManyField are defined. I tried your solution, I still get FieldError on Person it can't resolve x_training_trainings_attended into a field.